# Can't set push notitification sound when app in background - react native firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

How can I change the default push notification sound when app is in the background on android device?
I am using react native firebase notification implementation (https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/introduction).

I placed file pew1.mp3 in the res/raw folder
I send the message with this payload

```
{
"to" : "XXXX",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "body",
     "title": "title",
     "sound":"pew1.mp3"
 }
}
```

I tried with
1. "sound":"pew1" instead of "sound":"pew1.mp3"
2. "sound":"pew1.wav" with wav file in the resource folder